# How do I fix this websocket connection error with Velocity?

Tags: testing, meteor, jasmine, cucumber, meteor-velocity

I've tried out cucumber as well as jasmine with brand new projects, but all my tests are getting this failure. When I run:

```
$ meteor --test
```

I get:

```
stream error Network error: ws://localhost:3000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

This failure comes from a fresh application using the xolvio:cucumber package.

When I check out the mirror logs, it ends with:

```
[chimp] Finished running async processes with errors
stream error Network error: ws://localhost:3000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED
stream error Network error: ws://localhost:3000/websocket: connect ECONNREFUSED
Parent process ( 20797 ) is dead! Exiting cucumber
```

So, is this some kind of system error just for me? I have the latest Meteor: 1.1.0.2

I realize also this error used to be an old bug that's now considered fixed [in the meteor-cucumber repo](https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-cucumber/issues/25).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error it's actually a known issue and should not affect your spec runs.

When you run `meteor --test` it will start a main app and a mirror for cucumber to run on.

The message happens when the main app closes and the mirror is no longer able to access the main app through websockets. It's a harmless message.

Comment: how to fix it? because I can't get my app to run